# How do I display an alert over a PageViewController after a popover dismissal?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, uialertcontroller

I have a a VC structure like this

UIPageViewController -> detailViewController -> popoverviewcontroller

The popoverviewcontroller is dismissed using an unwind segue, bringing us back to the detailviewcontroller

Now, after the popover is done being dismissed, I would like to refresh the pages on the pagecontroller, since the action the user takes has changed the data.

I would also like to display an alert notifying the user about whether they were successful.

So I tried putting this code in the pageViewcontroller

```
- (IBAction) unwindFromPopup:(UIStoryboardSegue*)unwindSegue{
    [self refreshPages];
    UIAlertController * alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"alert" message:@"this should appear" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I tried moving the above code to the detail view controller instead, but I am getting no result from this. No error or anything, just a complete lack of alert. I put a breakpoint in the segue, and the code gets called. But no alert.

I thought of putting the code in one of the respective viewDidAppear methods, but for some reason viewDidAppear does not get called for either the pageviewcontroller or the detailview controller after I dismiss the popup.

So at this point I have no idea how to make this alert appear.

Do I need to post my full code, or is my problem apparent with the details I've included?

Comment: The *popover* should call it's ```beingDismissed``` method when it is done but I think you should look at using the detail (or page, not entirely clear) vc's presentation controller, setting ```presentationController.delegate``` to ```self``` and implement the delegate methods to do what you want here.

Comment: This is real tricky and the sequence of events are different if you segue or present or pop or show. You can also look at the popover's viewDidDisappear but then you need to also check if ```isMovingFromParentViewController``` is YES otherwise it could be because something else popped on screen.

Comment: Could you put the beingDismissed explanation as an answer? I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks - based on your comment ... long ago in a distant version of iOS I performed all the possible segues and noted what gets called when and have a table of that that I based my answer on. I must admit, nowadays I get most done using the presentation controller delegate.

Anyhow, to reply to your question, when you pop or modally present a controller, the controller *that is being presented* will message `beingPresented` and `beingDismissed` when it is done and you might be able to use this for what you are trying to do.

When you *push* a controller it will message `isMovingToParentViewController` when shown and `isMovingFromParentViewController` when dismissed, again in the controller being presented.

Back to a pop ... it will message `prepareForSegue` in the presenting VC and `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` in the presented VC and, when dismissing, will message *only* `viewWillDisappear` and `viewDidDisappear` in the presented VC, thus your problem. At least it will also message `beingDismissed` as mentioned and if you can use that I am really glad for you.

Comment: I was able to pass a callback from the pagecontroller to the popover, and call it in beingDismissed. That allowed me to run the code I wanted inside pageController. The alert works!