# How to prevent notitifcation observer from being called after UIViewController is popped?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, notifications

I have 2 `UIViewController` A and B. From A I `pushed` B and B has 2 `observers` for `reachability`. Now when I pop B and comes to A after this if Network goes off then the method written in VC B is called. I'm unable to figure it out that if B is already `popped` from `navigation stack` how it's method is called ?

**Note -**

1. I'm not having any property for VC B in VC A. Im always
   creating a new instance of VC B whenever pushing from VC A.
2. I also know I can remove observer in viewWillDisappear but still I want to
   know why observer is called even after the VC B is popped.

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64581143/how-do-i-display-an-alert-over-a-pageviewcontroller-after-a-popover-dismissal/64595933#64595933

Comment: For now I am already using the "isMovingFromParentViewController" flag check to remove observers but still my question remain unsolved. Why observers called even after viewcontroller is popped ?

Comment: When the VC pops you should not have a strong reference to it anywhere any longer. The problem could be there, but in this case, even if you have a strong reference, after removing the observer it should *never* be called again so something somewhere is not right. Maybe you are not removing it correctly? Show some code?

Comment: I'm not removing observers anywhere is this causing issues ? Does observer holds a strong reference ?

Comment: ??? I thought in 2. you said you remove the observer? You either need to ensure there are no strong references to the VC or you need to remove the observer when done. Otherwise, here is an idea. Why not use a flag ... I'll post some code to illustrate

Comment: My bad, Updated the language.

Comment: I have now removed observer in view will disappear inside isMovingFromParentViewController flag condition and It's working. Thanks for your help

Comment: Ok great!!! To answer question - after the VC is popped if you have a strong reference to it somewhere it stays around until that reference goes out of scope. Depending on how you create and use it it is easy to have a strong reference lying around for longer than needed. But I don't think that is what is happening, there is some cleanup happening as you navigate so VC stays around anyhow until all UI stuff is done, so it is easy for something like this to happen. So nice way to prevent it is to use flag or to remove it when you no longer want to react to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about if you use a flag that you switch on in `viewWillAppear` and off in `viewWillDisappear` and also in other relevant places e.g. in `isMovingFromParentViewController` or what applies based on how you present it. Then you can flag your action when the observer triggers. Here is an outline.

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) BOOL flag;

@end

@implementation ViewController

// Action triggered by observer
- ( void ) someAction
{
    if ( self.flag )
    {
        // do it
    }
}

// Switch on
- ( void ) viewWillAppear:( BOOL ) animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.flag = YES;
}

// Switch off
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.flag = NO;
}

@end
```

This is pretty simple. It is easy to maintain and debug and also if you need to at some stage switch on or off the action based on some other reason, it is easy to accommodate.

PS : You really need to show some code ... it is difficult to give more specific answer without you giving any code.